# Is it possible to compare the data in pdf with excel work sheet

Tags: automated-testing

My job is to compare the data in Pdf with Excel work Sheet to check weather the data is correct.

- For that is there any tool to compare?

Or

- Is there any java code in eclipse for testing?

Answer (score 3):

It is. Check out [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) project, it supports both formats (and much more)

- [TIKA - Extracting PDF](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/tika/tika_extracting_pdf.htm)
- [POI - Working with Excel](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

You can also use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for this as:

- JMeter is free and open source
- Given you have Tika libraries in the classpath - supports the same file types
- Provides [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to conditionally fail samplers basing on response data

See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-extract-data-files-jmeter) article for comprehensive step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Using JMeter here seems an overkill. JMeter is for performance testing. Plain Java with JUnit/TestNG will work well with TIKA and POI libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. It is just a [simple matter programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SimpleMatterOfProgramming). How hard it will be depends on your programming skills (which might be lacking, if your preferred solution is a plugin for Eclipse).

You need to do a research for PDF parser in language of your choice. Or tool to convert PDF to text, then parse such text in your language of choice. If your language is Java, you will have many tools (but Java is less than optimal for text parsing, even if it is possible).